# Cannot connect to my Google accounts anymore

Tags: mail.app, gmail, accounts, google

I'm on macOS 10.13.6 and Mail just started to prompt me to authenticate to connet to my two gmail accounts. So I did, using two-factor-authentication, everything seemed to work fine until the last step, when the window contents cleared, but the window would not close. It just sits there, has a cancel button and nothing else.

[image]

I can wait forever, the window will not close, I can force quite Mail in which case I need to restart the process with the same result or I can click Cancel ("Abbrechen") in which case I also would need to restart the process.

I even tried to remove the account from the OS entirely and then to re-add it, but it also lets me not finish this process. It sits at this window then and does nothing:

[image]

I clicked "Finish" (Fertig) there, then the button grays out, but the window just stays there and the account is not added eventually.

How can I resolve this issue and connect to my Google accounts again. Updating my OS is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you have **default browser** other than **Safari** you will face this issue.

- **Solution one**: changing default browser to **Safari**
- **Alternative solution**: When you see it stuck, start **Safari** and it will magically work.

Comment: Wow, good find. I mean, I cannot test it right now, but it’s quite possible that I opened Safari at some point and then it worked. Will mark this as the solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, great. Just after starting the bounty I gave it one more test and now it works … Unfortunately I cannot cancel the bounty, so: sorry for the fuzz. Not sure why it was not working earlier.

So, fair warning: I will not award the bounty (unless someone comes along and gives a solution how to solve the problem when it occurs again).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that the window for the Google login was blank but hovering over it with the mouse cursor revealed that the elements were there so it had to be a rendering issue. From the top menu bar (Safari) I chose `View -> Reload Page (⌘R)` and voilà!